# Complete previous typeset when re-typesetting in TexShop

Tags: compiling, texshop, auxiliary-files, console

It is really annoying when a typesetting error happens in TexShop. It presents you a console and from there you can go to the error. After you fix the error you re-typeset and then boom — you are screwed because TexShop messed up the aux file (most likely).

This does not happen when you complete the typesetting by entering `x` into the console. But when you do this the console disappears (behind the pdf if you have a small display and everything is on top of one another) and you cannot go to error easily.

Is it possible to tell TexShop to *complete* the ongoing typeset process before starting a new one?

Comment: `x` does not complete it stops at that point. `s` would complete.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the placeholder says `[s] ignore all, [x] complete`. In the end, the point is not about which key should be pressed, I just want to know whether TexShop can gracefully handle the ongoing typeset process so it will not break the following typesetting

Comment: whatever texshop does it depends a lot on how tex is responding to the error, if you have an error in a section heading then tex quite likely trashed the aux file before detecting the error, so you will need to delete it however you terminate the current run.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is simply that the console goes behind the preview window when you use `x` in the console, you can simply tell TeXShop to keep editing. This will keep to console visible but the editing window as the selected window:

`TeXShop > Preferences > Typesetting > After Typesetting > Continue Editing`

This would allow you to typeset, get an error, use `x` to stop where you are or `s` to finish the entire file while ignoring errors, go to the error using the console (or the keyboard shortcut) as it is still in the foreground, fix the error and then typeset again.